# Can not fully qualify enum, Is it a bug?

Tags: c#

This had me stumped for a few minutes. For some reason I can not qualify the Constants in the 'Test' class below. The compiler thinks that 'A' is the end of the 'A.B.A' namespace and therefore does not see the Constants. Can anyone tell me why qualification 'A.B.Constants.Constants.A' does not work here?

```
namespace A.B.Constants
{
    public class Constants
    {
        public enum A
        {
            A,
            B
        };
    }
}

namespace A.B.A
{
    public class Test
    {
        A.B.Constants.Constants.A enumA; // Error here on the 'B'
        Constants.Constants.A secondEnumA; // This works
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any `using` statements?

Comment: No, there are no usings in the example

Comment: Please see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't tell you why this is (boring answer: because the C# spec say so - but this does not give any insight). Here's a workaround:

```
global::A.B.Constants.Constants.A enumA;
```

Use the `global::` prefix or an extern alias.

Comment: Really weird to experience this after almost 10 years of programming in C# for the first time!